# mysql recover backup error on data with tinyint(1)

Tags: php, mysql, tinyint, r1soft

I've a mysterious problems and i'm asking you a little help.

When i recover a db from r1soft all the data > 1 contained in a table with tinyint(1)  is converted to 1

example:

**mytable_user**

```
+----+-------+--------------------+
| ID | data1 | data2 (tintint(1)) |
+----+-------+--------------------+
|  1 |    55 |     4              |
|  1 |    44 |     6              |
+----+-------+--------------------+
```

When i recover the backup all the values in data2 is recovered with value 1

How this happens??

Thanks

Comment: How exactly are you "recovering the backup"?

Comment: Automatically from the r1soft menu. Thanks

Comment: So basically, this r1soft does something and nobody knows what, and something goes wrong? You may be better off contacting their support, not sure you'll get a lot of help here.

Comment: Ok thanks, i was wondering that the problem is tinyint(1) error